# Python: pass the path as an argument

Tags: python-3.x

i need to write a script in python, which run a process (notepad.exe). The probelm is, i dont know the path of the process so i need to pass the path of the process as an argument.

How does it work?

Answer (score 0):

The command-line arguments to your script are stored as a list in [`sys.argv`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/sys.html#sys.argv).

To run a process, use the [`subprocess`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/subprocess) module.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following. In a file called exe.py put:

import os

import sys

os.popen(sys.argv[1])

## #

Usage:

C:\Python32>python exe.py notepad.exe